# How do IT administrators create the email accounts for students?

Tags: email

I was wondering, as yearly, universities get lots of students per year, how are all of the email accounts created? Are they created one by one?

Comment: Only if IT is completely incompetent...

Comment: Arguably, one possible definition of a computer is "a device to automate repetitive tasks so humans don't have to do them".

Comment: @DanielR.Collins - or, perhaps, to automate repetitive tasks so that humans can assign more of them to others?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about IT systems administration, not academia.

Answer (score 2):

Just to have a clear answer here... although, yes, the question invites humorous responses! :)

No, such IT tasks are highly automated, by running "scripts" with super-user privileges to create/initialize accounts, create pseudo-random temporary passwords, and so on. On Unix/Linux underlying systems (which are common in academe) these scripts would often be "shell scripts" ("bash" or "cshell" or "zshell" or others), or Perl scripts.

In my observation, this sort of "scripting task", and the means to accomplish it, are so far removed from most peoples' experience that it is hard to imagine how it works/happens. So the question is in many regards reasonable.

The recent trend of glossy graphical interfaces adds to the difficulty of understanding the essentials of what's really happening. No kitties, puppies, or dancing bears involved! :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my case is not exactly what you asked but it worths mentioning.

Working as a system administrator at a K-12 international school in Vietnam for 5 years, I'd created a system that can generate the student user accounts in batch with the following options:

1. Automatically create the accounts if they're marked as enrolled in the Student information system.
2. Only create the student accounts (in batch of-course) when I press a button on the web interface.
3. Use the web interface to create each student account manually.

The system comprises of 2 parts:

1. Backend: a combination of python and shell scripts to generate the AD accounts.
2. Frontend: I used Django for the ease of web implementation.

Hope that will help.